# Did this character steal this other character's body?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2, a series of events at the end of the movie seem odd and, when taken together over several viewings, make it seem that.

> Yondu might have taken Rocket's body instead of dying.

Here are the events:

1. Rocket re-assembles Yondu's arrow skillfully enough that another character is able to control the arrow.
2. Then,

> During Yondu's funeral, Rocket gets very emotional and tells Peter that ".... Even though he said mean things to me and stole batteries he didn't need.". (This seems to be a reference to Rocket steeling batteries earlier in the movie.

Peter responds by.

> Doing a double take and then saying " Well, of course not".

3. The very last frames of the movie before the credits are of

> Rocket crying while watching the colorful show of Yondu's funeral.

Also note that.

> Rocket is cybernetically engineered, and that Yondu's experience controlling the arrow might make it easy for Yondu to control an engineered body.

**Is there precedent for Yondu steeling Rocket's body?  And have the makers of the movie commented on this?**

I noticed these things the first time I saw the movie, but I waited to post it as a question until after I had the chance to watch the movie closely a few more times. This subplot element was placed so dryly that Peter's confused expression can pass by as an unexplained anomaly.  I am adding the Marvel tag in case the comics shed light on this.

Comment: I've reread this 5 times and I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @phantom42 I think he's asking if there's any support in the comics canon for his particular theory.

Comment: No one's disputing that you have the quote right, you just aren't getting its meaning.

Comment: I've seen the movie plenty of times. I know exactly what the dialogue was, word for word. I also understand what the dialogue _means_. It doesn't mean what you think it means. I'm not trying to be rude here, but you're just mistaken.

Comment: I don't quite get the jump between controlling the arrow and possessing another person's body. I mean, we have machinery in the real world that responds to brain waves, and that in no way relates to taking someone over. As for Rocket, he's augmented, by he isn't a robot. He's an intelligent living being - taking him over is taking over a person, not a machine. Can you elaborate on why you believe Yondu has that ability?

Answer (score 23):

First off, no, there's no support for the idea that Yondu somehow inhabited Rocket's body in any source material that I know of. And more to the point, there's not much support in the *movie* for that idea either.

The big mistake you're making, I think, is that you are missing the whole point of Rocket's speech during the funeral. When he says:

> "They came back, even though he was mean, and yelled at them, and stole batteries he didn't need."

Rocket isn't talking about Yondu anymore. He's talking about *himself*. During their trip together, both as captives of the Ravagers and later flying to Ego, Yondu tries to explain to Rocket how similar the two of them are, and how Rocket's behavior is a way to shield himself from becoming close to people who might leave him. Yondu tries to convince Rocket that there are some people he can count on, even if they may not seem like it.

In the end, the Ravagers -- who had exiled Yondu for misbehaving -- still forgave him and returned to perform the funeral rights. Rocket is applying that same idea to *himself* -- even though he's done things to get the Guardians in trouble, like stealing batteries, he now realizes they will stick with him.

Peter's response bears that idea out:

> Of course they did.

Rocket also realizes that Yondu really *was* a friend, at the end. And he's sad that Yondu is gone, but also happy and relieved that the Ravagers came back to pay their respects, as it gives him hope for his own future. That's why he was crying.

---

The thing with the arrow is much easier to explain. Yondu's head fin is what allows him to make the appropriate noises to control the arrow, and Kraglin has both. Rocket, being a highly skilled mechanic, was able to repair the arrow once he had all the parts, and Kraglin is able to use the arrow for the same reason Yondu did, though he's clearly not very good at it.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I would point out, however, that I doubt the headfin is what allows Kraglin (or, for that matter, Yondu) to whistle.  More likely, it's what translates the sounds (or, more likely, nerve impulses which are used in whistling) into commands for the arrow.